# Should i create a new SecretKey for every String that i want to encrypt?

Tags: keystore, caesar-cipher, secret-key

I want to encrypt the `firstName` and the `lastName` of every person that creates an account and store the encrypted file into the database.
and then decrypt them back only when a secure request comes to the `@RestController`

I use `Cipher` class which comes from `javax.crypto.Cipher`
and I store the key I use for encrypting in a `KeyStore.getInstance("JCEKS")`

my question is, should I create a new `SecretKey` for every item that I want to encrypt or create one key and do all the work with that?

in other words, should `userOne`'s informations get encrypted/decrypted with `secretKeyEntryOne`, `userTwo` - `secretKeyEntryTwo`, `userThree` - `secretKeyEntryThree` and so on **OR** all the informations of all users should be encrypted/decrypted with `globalSecretKey` ?

if you don't understand what I mean by this question, Please, just let me know and I'll edit my question.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR: Have many ciphers(`SecretKey`). It provides better safety.

---

From a security standpoint, it would be best to have a `SecretKey` for each user as it will reduce the chances of having all your user's information leaked in the case of a data breach where your `globalSecretKey` gets leaked. Having many `SecretKey` does a better job at protecting this information as the worst case scenario is that only one client's information get breached.

Should you not wish to have a million different combinations, you can have a list (around 500; more === better) with `ciphers` that get selected at random. This reduces the chance of all user's data getting breached. Although if you have the space to store each user as a special key, I suggest that you do that instead.